# no assets when generating jpg with KnpSnappyBundle

Tags: symfony

This seems to be a know issue but I can't find a solution:

css files are not being loaded when generating a jpg/pdf with KnpSnappyBundle.
[Here is a discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/symfony2/browse_thread/thread/b16266e9bd14628d/587d0f05493aa836?lnk=gst&q=KnpSnappyBundle#587d0f05493aa836) on google groups, but no answer is provided.

Has anyone found a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 5):

A little late for an answer but I had the same problem and I solved it using absolute paths for my assets like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ app.request.scheme ~'://' ~ app.request.httpHost ~ asset('bundles/factura/css/all.css') }}">
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

There is a "workaround" on [github](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle/pull/13) but it's still on merge request:
At the moment I think it's the best solution to use

```
$this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutput()
```

instead of

```
$this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml()
```