# Symfony2 Knp-snappy to generate PDF doesn't import CSS

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, pdf

I would like to generate a pdf from an html.twig template but something wrong...

In fact, the PDF has been create with the good content but there is no layout. It's seems the CSS files are not import...

I use Bootstrap from twitter to manage the layout.

Here the part of my controller

```
 $filename = "CI-TRI-".$Chrono->getChrono();
            $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->generateFromHtml(
                                                            $this->renderView('WebStoreMainBundle:Admin:customInvoiceTemplate.html.twig', array('User'=>$User,'Parts'=>$parts, 'device'=>$device, 'rate'=>$rate)),
                                                            __DIR__.'/../../../../web/download/'.$filename.'.pdf'
                                                            );
```

And here my layout :

```
<html>
<head>
     {% block stylesheets %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('bootstrap/css/customInvoice.css') }}">
        <base href="http://{{app.request.host}}">
        <meta charset="UTF-8" >
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block header %}
        <div class="span2">
            <img src="{{ asset('bootstrap/img/GTO_logo.png') }}">
        </div>
    {% endblock %}

    {% block content %}

    {% endblock %}

</body>
```

Wish someone can help me..

PS: Sorry for the typos, english is not my native language.

Comment: What give you 'app.request.host' ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526157/no-assets-when-generating-jpg-with-knpsnappybundle

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The assets must be linked using absolute paths. So instead of:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css') }}">
```

It should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yourdomain.com/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
```

I had this issue myself and this sorted it out for me.

Comment: I got a timeout with this. Any idea?

Comment: @Soullivaneuh completely depends on what you've done so far. Best bet is to check to make sure you can open the CSS through the browser properly. If you can, then I'd post it as a question.

Comment: See this answer for a portable solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049712/how-to-use-absolute-path-in-twig-functions

Answer (score 14):

It would be easier to supply absolute parameter like that:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css', absolute=true) }}">
```

Comment: only applicable to version 2.5 and above

Answer (score 5):

Take note when using Symfony 2.7, Twig has removed absolute argument for asset() function.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ absolute_url(asset('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css')) }}">
```

See [New in Symfony 2.7: the new Asset component](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-the-new-asset-component#template-function-changes) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

@user1805558's answer worked for me. I was also using Less, and used this, which some may find helpful to see:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets filter='lessphp' combine=true output='css/pdf.css.twig'
        '../app/Resources/assets/css/pdf.less'
    %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset(asset_url, absolute=true) }}"/>
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: for me this throws a twig error (symfony 2.8), i went with this solution: `href="{{ app.request.scheme ~'://' ~ app.request.httpHost ~ asset_url }}"`

Answer (score 0):

UP for absolute option in asset call :

```
<img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/AVNZ-Logo-H-SMALL.jpg', absolute=true) }}">
```

It's related in official bundle repo :
https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle/issues/78

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. As commented in this [issue](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy/issues/159) your asset URLs need to be absolute.

This can be accomplished in symfony using the **asset** twig funtion and "package urls":

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#assets-base-urls

For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css') }}">
```

And then, in your ***app/config/config.yml***

```
framework:
# ...
templating:
    assets_base_urls:
        http:
            - "http://yourdomain.com/"
```

If you are in your local configuration, inside your **config_dev.yml** you should use a different URL instead, like:

```
    - "http://localhost/myproject/web/"
```